# Sum of Subset using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I have used for calculating subset using

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([15,1,4,6,3,10,4.2])
num = 8.2

def subsetsum(array,num):

    if num == 0 or num < 1:
        return None
    elif len(array) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if array[0] == num:
            return [array[0]]
        else:
            with_v = subsetsum(array[1:],(num - array[0])) 
            if with_v:
                return [array[0]] + with_v
            else:
                return subsetsum(array[1:],num)

print('\nList of Values : ',array)
print('\nSum Desired : ',num)
print('\nValues that add up to sum : ',subsetsum(array,num))
```

**Output for Integer Values**

```
List of Values :  [15  1  4  6  3 10  4]

Sum Desired :  8

Values that add up to sum :  [1, 4, 3]
```

Now, how can I implement the same using PANDAS Dataframe rather than using Numpy Array?

Comment: I corrected the indentation. Check if it's correct.

Comment: "Translate this code for me" is generally not a very good way to ask questions. Please explain what the code is supposed to do on a sample.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the sample. I am not asking to translate the code, just how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally translate this by replacing `np.array` with `pd.Series` and adding `.iloc` after `array` everywhere, to use indexing by position. This is what I did below.

By the way, you really want to have integers there. If the numbers are given to you with a few decimal places, convert to integers by using something like  `round(x*100)`. Trying to achieve equality of sums of floating point numbers is a recipe for frustration: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is False.

And most importantly: there is no advantage whatsoever of using Pandas here. It's a module for analyzing data, not for solving combinatorial problems. It uses NumPy under the hood, so what you get is a slower code with additional overhead of Pandas layers of indexing data.

If you want to improve the performance of the code, I suggest sorting the array in descending order before beginning, so that the too-large-to-be-used values are quickly moved out of the way.

```
import pandas as pd
array = pd.Series([15,1,4,6,3,10,4])
num = 8

def subsetsum(array,num):

    if num == 0 or num < 1:
        return None
    elif len(array) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if array.iloc[0] == num:
            return [array.iloc[0]]
        else:
            with_v = subsetsum(array.iloc[1:], (num - array.iloc[0]))
            if with_v:
                return [array.iloc[0]] + with_v
            else:
                return subsetsum(array.iloc[1:],num)

print('\nList of Values : ',array)
print('\nSum Desired : ',num)
print('\nValues that add up to sum : ',subsetsum(array,num))
```